# Replace newline with |

Tags: powershell

Any idea how I can replace newline with a `|` in the code below?

```
Get-ADforest | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Domains
```

I've tried the code below with no success:

```
(Get-ADforest | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Domains).Replace("`n", "|")
```

and

```
(Get-ADforest | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Domains).Replace("`r", "|")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The best answer is below.

    (Get-ADforest | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Domains) -join " | "

Comment: Your output is actually an array of values. In order to combine them together you could use -Join operator with willing join expression, like so: $ArrayOfValues -Join '|'